# How to make string that contain date and two strings

Tags: c

I need to make a string that contain STRING1_NUMBER_DATE
when the date must be in :YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOUR_MIN
I was using

```
time_t rowtime;
sprintf(Buffer,"%s_%d_%s",STRING1,NUMBER,ctime(&rowtime));
```

Two problems:
1. Do I have to make the NUMBER to a string first?
2. And the date is not in the structure I wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure the date as follows:

```
time_t rowtime;
char buff[20];
strftime(buff, 20, "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M", localtime(&rowtime));

sprintf(Buffer, "%s_%d_%s", STRING1, NUMBER, buff);
```

printing the `NUMBER` like you did is fine.

Comment: first of all, thx!
i will try it in a few min and will add you a points